# unable to save data from CSV file to DB in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I'm unable to save data into DB from `CSV` file in `Spring Batch`. I've taken a reference from link: **http://www.javabeat.net/spring-batch-example/?et_monarch_popup=true**, when executing the `Main` method, I see following tables gets created, but it don't create `Employee` table. **Why? Please guide, what's wrong happening here?**

This doesn't have employee table, also if I create it, it doesn't save data for employee table.
[image]

Employee.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String empId;
    private String city;
    private String country;

    @XmlElement(name="EMP_ID")
    public String getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
    public void setEmpId(String empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="CITY")
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="COUNTRY")
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

EmployeeDataMapper.java

```
public class EmployeeDataMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Employee>{

    @Override
    public Employee mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setEmpId(fieldSet.readString(0));
        employee.setCity(fieldSet.readString(1));
        employee.setCountry(fieldSet.readString(2));
        return employee;
    }
}
```

OrderItemWriter.java

```
public class OrderItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Employee> {
    private static final String INSERT_EMPLOYEE = "insert into employee(empid,city,country) values(?,?,?)";
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void write(List<? extends Employee> employees) throws Exception {
        for (Employee order : employees) {
            jdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_EMPLOYEE, order.getCity(),order.getCountry(), order.getCountry());
        }
    }

    public OrderItemWriter(DataSource ds) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String[] config = { "job-config.xml" };

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(config);

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("employeeJob");

        try {
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("~~~~~ Finished Execution of Batch Job ~~~~~~");
    }
}
```

job-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- stored job-meta in memory
    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" /> </bean>-->

    <!-- stored job-meta in database -->
     <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseType" value="mysql" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

job-config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="datasource-config.xml" />
    <import resource="job-context.xml" />

    <!-- JOB -->
    <job id="employeeJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="employeeprocessor">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" commit-interval="3" skip-limit="2">
                    <skippable-exception-classes>
                        <include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException" />
                    </skippable-exception-classes>
                </chunk>
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>


    <!-- ItemReader -->
    <bean id="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="resource" value="classpath:input/employees.csv" />

        <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />

        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="names" value="EMP_ID,CITY,COUNTRY" />
                        <property name="delimiter" value="," />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <bean class="javabeat.net.EmployeeDataMapper" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="writer" class="javabeat.net.OrderItemWriter">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

datasource-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">


    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />

        <!-- connect to database -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.mysql.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.mysql.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.mysql.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.mysql.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <!-- create job-meta tables automatically In production you don't need to
        create this every time. Just create once in production. -->
    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>
 </beans>
```

employees.csv

```
1,Pune,India
```

**Edit-1:**
When I debug the code, I see debug coming on below code

```
public OrderItemWriter(DataSource ds) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }
```

But `write()` method not executing. Why ?

DB table I created for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE `batch`.`employee` (
  `empId` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  `city` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `country` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`empId`)
 );
```

database.properties:

```
jdbc.mysql.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.mysql.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/batch
jdbc.mysql.username=root
jdbc.mysql.password=password
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <springframework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springbatch.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</springbatch.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.31</mysql.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.8</joda-time.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring XML to/back object -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springbatch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>${springbatch.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: In your `jbdcTemplate.update()` method you are not passing `empId` but passing `country` twice. The error can be because your table have some constraints on the `empId`.

Comment: Of course, you'll have to create the table in DB manually. You are doing `update()` remember?

Comment: I have you have created bean of `OrderItemWriter` class and then injected it properly in your service class using `@Autowired` or a setter.

Comment: I see that you are creating the bean of `OrderItemWriter` and injecting it in your Job. Seems like there is some other issue with your code.

Comment: Please see Edit-1 above, write() method not executing, We need to findout what is the issue?

Comment: Ok, I will try to send it, I've not done this before :)

Comment: Their chat system showing some temporary error.

Comment: I still don't understand why it's not calling write method?

Comment: No clue. The code looks correct to me.

Comment: Do you think its something to do with Spring Framework version or spring batch version?

Comment: No, I don't think this is version problem.

Comment: Are you also facing same issue at your end ? Even EmployeeDataMapper also not calling...

Comment: I suggest you to read http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

Comment: Thnx FreezY - The question is how we can fixed the issue exist in the above code, definelty your provided links code will work, but I expect / feel above code should also be get solved. That's my request.